# Highlight current item in the heading php

Tags: php, html, css, header, include

So I was wondering how do you highlight the current page in the heading of the website. I used the include method to call the heading in all of the pages, but how do I highlight the current page while maintaining the include method in every page.

**HEADER.PHP**

```
        <div id="site-content">
            
            <header class="site-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="index.php" id="branding">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Company Name" class="logo" width="100">
                        <div class="branding-copy">
                            <h1 class="site-title" style="font-size:60px;">Benedicto Law</h1>
                            <small class="site-description">Justice In Words</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <nav class="main-navigation">
                        <button type="button" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="attorney.php">Attorney</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="service.php">Service</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <nav class="mobile-navigation"></nav>
                </div>
            </header> <!-- .site-header -->
```

then I only used
`<?php  include_once('header.php') ?>` for calling it to other pages.
I wanted it to highlight the current menu item where the user is in.
For example:
The user pressed Attorney button the Attorney button in the heading should have a highlight.
Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options.

**1. Pass the data in PHP manually**

Before your `include(header` statement, create a variable for the onPage and set it. Then use it in your include.

For example:

```
<?php  
$onPage = 'attorney';
include_once('header.php') ?>
```

Then in header.php, check for it like this:

```
<li class="menu-item <?php if ($onPage == 'attorney') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="attorney.php">Attorney</a></li>
```

**2. Automatically detect it**

In header.php

```
$onPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
// make sure it's getting just the page, no directory
$onPage= explode("/",$onPage);
$onPage = $onPage[count($onPage-1)];
// remove .php and make sure its lower case
$onPage = str_replace(".php", "", strtolower($onPage));
// for /directory/Attorney.php this will give you 'attorney'
```

The check for it like before

```
<li class="menu-item <?php if ($onPage == 'attorney') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="attorney.php">Attorney</a></li>
```

Comment: Okay I just changed 'active' to the class that I want to use. It is working now thanks